# preg_match in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, mootools

Is it possible in `JavaScript` to do something like `preg_match` does in `PHP` ?

I would like to be able to get two numbers from string:

```
var text = 'price[5][68]';
```

into two separated variables:

```
var productId = 5;
var shopId    = 68;
```

Edit:
I also use `MooTools` if it would help.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

JavaScript has a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object which does what you want. The [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object has a [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function that will help you out.

```javascript
var matches = text.match(/price\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/);
var productId = matches[1];
var shopId    = matches[2];
```

Comment: For other googlers; `text.match` will return the result of the matching. so `var match = text.match(/price\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/)` and then `alert(match[1]);`

Answer (score 33):

```
var text = 'price[5][68]';
var regex = /price\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/gi;
match = regex.exec(text);
```

match[1] and match[2] will contain the numbers you're looking for.

Answer (score 24):

```
var thisRegex = new RegExp('\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]');

if(!thisRegex.test(text)){
    alert('fail');
}
```

I found test to act more preg_match as it provides a Boolean return.  However you do have to declare a RegExp var.

TIP: RegExp adds it's own / at the start and finish, so don't pass them.

Comment: You can also shorten this with `/\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/.test(text)`

Comment: I agree, as I was looking for how to reproduce the regex testing feature of preg_match when I saw the title of this question ;)

Comment: Using the RegExp class constructor has the benefit that if you need to interpolate a variable in the pattern, it takes a string!

Comment: Only works for me when escaping backslashes, like '\\[(\\d+)\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]'

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
var matches = text.match(/\[(\d+)\][(\d+)\]/);
var productId = matches[1];
var shopId = matches[2];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var myregexp = /\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/;
var match = myregexp.exec(text);
if (match != null) {
    var productId = match[1];
    var shopId = match[2];
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

get matched string back or false

```
function preg_match (regex, str) {
  if (new RegExp(regex).test(str)){
    return regex.exec(str);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to get image links within HTML content.
Like **preg_match_all** in PHP

```
let HTML = '<div class="imageset"><table><tbody><tr><td width="50%"><img src="htt ps://domain.com/uploads/monthly_2019_11/7/1.png.jpg" class="fr-fic fr-dii"></td><td width="50%"><img src="htt ps://domain.com/uploads/monthly_2019_11/7/9.png.jpg" class="fr-fic fr-dii"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>';
let re = /<img src="(.*?)"/gi;
let result = HTML.match(re);
```

out array

```
0: "<img src="htt ps://domain.com/uploads/monthly_2019_11/7/1.png.jpg""
1: "<img src="htt ps://domain.com/uploads/monthly_2019_11/7/9.png.jpg""
```

Answer (score 0):

## Some Googling brought me to [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kvz/locutus/master/src/php/pcre/preg_match.js) :

```js
function preg_match (regex, str) {
  return (new RegExp(regex).test(str))
}
console.log(preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$","test"))
console.log(preg_match("^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$","what@google.com"))
```

See https://locutus.io for more info.