# javascript preg_match equivilent

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preg_match in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291289/preg-match-in-javascript)

I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost/nafham/?selection/12/24/122
```

Using PHP I can do:

```
preg_match("#(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $regs)
$edu_year = $regs[1];
$semester = $regs[2];
$subject = $regs[3];
```

How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: This question is already answered in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291289/preg-match-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks but how to write the pattern in javascript, I tried: var myregexp = #(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)#; not working

Comment: var myregexp = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

String `.match` is what you are looking for or regex.exec

read http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

and http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html