# Preg_match in JS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, preg-match

HTML code

```
    <li class="btn-xs"><a tabindex="-1" 
    href="/admin/orders/restart/id/163148"   
    >Restart</a></li>
    <li class="btn-xs" style="display:none;"><a tabindex="-1" href="" data-
    toggle="modal" data-target="#check_alls_163148_s" 
    style="cursor:pointer;">Set&nbsp;start&nbsp;count</a></li>
    <li class="btn-xs"><a tabindex="-1" 
    href="/admin/orders/restart/id/162616">Restart</a></li>
    <li class="btn-xs" style="display:none;"><a tabindex="-1" href="" data-
    toggle="modal" data-target="#check_alls_162616_s" 
    style="cursor:pointer;">Set&nbsp;start&nbsp;count</a></li>
```

How can I extract `/admin/orders/restart/id/163148` and `/admin/orders/restart/id/162616` in js? I need to put it in an array.

I'm not good with preg_match. How can i extract /admin/orders/restart/id/163148 and /admin/orders/restart/id/162616 using js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_match in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291289/preg-match-in-javascript)

Comment: not duplicate.. in the other question there is only 1 .. in my example i need to return the first and the second one.. like in array

Comment: Do you just have this html as a string, or are you in a browser environment?

Comment: Please see [this answer](/a/1732454/2487517) regarding parsing HTML with Regexp

Comment: @mdziekon easy for u? so give me an answer :) can't help? dont comment! thanks!

Comment: @KubaKutiak not only this string its an html file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li.btn-xs a'))
               .map( a => a.getAttribute("href") )
               .filter( href => href && href.length > 0 )
```

Or, with added fluff:

```js
function selectByNonBlank() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li.btn-xs a')).map( a => a.getAttribute("href") ).filter( a => a && a.length > 0 );
}

function selectByRestart() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li.btn-xs a')).filter( a => a.innerHTML == "Restart" ).map( a => a.getAttribute("href") );
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", function() { console.log(selectByRestart()); });
document.getElementById("href").addEventListener("click", function() { console.log(selectByNonBlank()); });
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
```

```html
<li class="btn-xs"><a tabindex="-1" href="/admin/orders/restart/id/163148"   >Restart</a></li>
<li class="btn-xs" style="display:none;"><a tabindex="-1" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#check_alls_163148_s" style="cursor:pointer;">Set&nbsp;start&nbsp;count</a></li>
<li class="btn-xs"><a tabindex="-1" href="/admin/orders/restart/id/162616"   >Restart</a></li>
              <li class="btn-xs" style="display:none;"><a tabindex="-1" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#check_alls_162616_s" style="cursor:pointer;">Set&nbsp;start&nbsp;count</a></li>
<button id="restart">Select by Restart</button>
<button id="href">Select by non blank href</button>
```

Comment: i only need to extract the href where there is "Restart" after the in the <a></a>

Comment: @PaulE That requirement isn't in the question, but it's easy enough to handle

Comment: @PaulE Try that (the fluffy version)

Comment: Thank you so much!